# Enumerate lines with same ID in awk

Tags: awk

I'm using `awk` to process the following [sample] of data:

```
id,desc
168048,Prod_A
217215,Prod_C
217215,Prod_B
168050,Prod_A
168050,Prod_F
168050,Prod_B
```

What I'm  trying to do is to create a column `'item'` enumerating the lines within the same `'id'`:

```
id,desc,item
168048,Prod_A,#1
217215,Prod_C,#1
217215,Prod_B,#2
168050,Prod_A,#1
168050,Prod_F,#2
168050,Prod_B,#3
```

Here what I've tried:

```
BEGIN {
  FS = ","
  a = 1
}
NR != 1 {
  if (id != $1) {
    id = $1
    printf "%s,%s\n", $0, "#"a
  }
  else {
    printf "%s,%s\n", $0, "#"a++
  }
}
```

But it messes the numbering:

```
168048,Prod_A,#1
217215,Prod_C,#1
217215,Prod_B,#1
168050,Prod_A,#2
168050,Prod_F,#2
168050,Prod_B,#3
```

Could someone give me some hints?

P.S. The line order doesn't matter

Comment: Your code only increments `a`, it never resets it.

Comment: Are the entries in column 1 guaranteed to be grouped such that all the entries for a code, say `168050`, are adjacent to each other in the file, or do you have to deal with the possibility that lines 10, 100 and 1000 may all list code `234912` (without any of the intervening lines listing the same code)?  It's possible (and not particularly hard) to handle this, but there's no point in doing so if it isn't necessary.

Comment: @melpomene indeed, I still do not understand some akw functionaties... But thanks for your comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is possible that the id repeats itself, but I created a column (that I omitted) that joins the id field with others fields, mitigating the possibility of duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{print $0,"#"++c[$1]}' OFS=, file
168048,Prod_A,#1
217215,Prod_C,#1
217215,Prod_B,#2
168050,Prod_A,#1
168050,Prod_F,#2
168050,Prod_B,#3
```

#### How it works

- `-F,`

  This sets the field separator on input to a comma.
- `NR>1{...}`

  This limits the commands in braces to lines other than the first,  that is, the one with the header.
- `print $0,"#"++c[$1]`

  This prints the line followed by `#` and a count of the number of times that we have seen the first column.

  Associative array `c` keeps a count of the number of times that an `id` has been seen.  For every line, we increment by 1 the count for `id` `$1`.  `++` increments.  Because `++` precedes `c[$1]`, the increment is done *before* the value if printed.
- `OFS=,`

  This sets the field separator on output to a comma.

#### Printing a new header as well

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{print $0,"item"} NR>1{print $0,"#"++c[$1]}' OFS=, file
id,desc,item
168048,Prod_A,#1
217215,Prod_C,#1
217215,Prod_B,#2
168050,Prod_A,#1
168050,Prod_F,#2
168050,Prod_B,#3
```

Comment: Note that this accommodates the 'codes are not necessarily all grouped together' scenario mentioned in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797466/enumerate-lines-with-same-id-in-awk#comment66888167_39797466) to the main question.